# How can I change <h1> through <h6> to have same padding as <p> using em instead of px while keeping them all the same?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

No code, just a simple concept I need help with:

I want the padding above/below all text items *(h1-h6, p, blockquote, code, etc.)* to be the same. I want it to be 1em=16px. But, if I set them all to have 1em paddings then the larger-text items like h1 have more padding because it's 1em relative to h1's font-size. How can I make them all have it be 1em relative to p's font-size?

I don't want to use pixels as a set width because then doubling the page's text to 1em=32px size wouldn't double the padding making it half what it needs to be. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you thought about getting rid of all padding and margin on the text elements and using "line height" instead? A blank block element can be used for spacing.

Comment: Have you considered using `rem` instead of `em`? `1rem` is constant, independent of the current element’s font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use other unit like [rem, ch, ex](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You set the font size of <h1>, <h2> relative to the font size of the surrounding text, and you compute the padding in ems to be the same as the padding of <p>.

For example:

```
body { font-size: 24px; }
p    { padding-top: 1em; }
h1   { font-size: 1.25em;
       padding-top: 0.8em; /* = 1 / 1.25 */
     }
```

The visual gap will still be different because you have not said anything about margins and line-heights.

Check out how it works (note how 0.5 = 0.625 / 1.25):

```html
<style>
  p, h1 { border: 1px solid red; }
  p { padding-top: 0.625em;
      padding-bottom: 0.625em; }
  h1 { font-size: 1.25em;
       padding-top: 0.5em;
       padding-bottom: 0.5em; }
  span { background: #DDEEFF; }
</style>

<p>This is some text which is intended as a filler to demonstrate a point.
This is some text which is intended as a filler to demonstrate a point.
This is some text which is intended as a filler to demonstrate a point.
This is some text which is intended as a filler to demonstrate a point.
This is some text which is intended as a filler to demonstrate a point.</p>

<p><span>This is some more text which is intended as a filler to demonstrate a point.
This is some more text which is intended as a filler to demonstrate a point.
This is some more text which is intended as a filler to demonstrate a point.
This is some more text which is intended as a filler to demonstrate a point.
This is some more text which is intended as a filler to demonstrate a point.</span></p>

<h1><span>Heading with the same padding as the paragraphs</span></h1>

<p>This is some other text which is intended as a filler to demonstrate a point.
This is some other text which is intended as a filler to demonstrate a point.
This is some other text which is intended as a filler to demonstrate a point.
This is some other text which is intended as a filler to demonstrate a point.
This is some other text which is intended as a filler to demonstrate a point.</p>
```